# How to generate a element dynamically after a specific element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textfield

I am generating a textfield dynamically using javascript. The problem is that the new textfield is generated before the file type. I want to generate it after the file type and in a new row. i Have shared the code.

html

```
<input type="text" name="textf"/>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QxPbJ/2/

Hope you understand

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you be more specific, plz. As I understand, you want to generate a new textField after you type something, like .txt into the old text field, not after clicking inside the textbox. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
$(function () {
    count = 2;
    var createNewField = function () {
        var node = $('<tr><td></td><td><input type="radio" name="choices" name="o" id="o" style="float:left"/><div class="XYZ" style="float:left"><input style="margin-bottom:20px; " class="ABC" type="text" name="option" id="option" placeholder="add option' + count + '"/></div>&emsp;<input type="file"/></td></tr>');
        if (count < 6) {
            $('input').last().after(node);
            count++;
            node.click(function () {
                createNewField();
            });
        };
    };
    $('input.ABC').click(function () {
        createNewField();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not using table but you are appending tr and td. First place table after the field and add tr to it

Answer (score 0):

Try this link [Click here](http://jsfiddle.net/QxPbJ/3/)

Html

```
<input type="radio" name="choices"/>
<input style="margin-bottom:20px;"id="option1" class="ABC" name="option1"type="text"/>
<input type="file" name="op" id="op"/>
<div id="appendBefore"></div>
```

Js

```
$(function () {
  count = 2;
  var createNewField = function() {
  var $node = $('<tr><td></td><td><input type="radio" name="choices" name="o" id="o"     style="float:left"/><div class="XYZ" style="float:left"><input style="margin-bottom:20px; " class="ABC" type="text" name="option" id="option" placeholder="add option '+count+'"/>   </div>&emsp;<input type="file"/></td></tr>');
  if(count < 6){
    $node.find("input.ABC").one('click', createNewField);
    $('#appendBefore').before($node);
    count = count+1;
  }
};
$('input.ABC').one('click', createNewField);
});
```